# SSRS Expression Conversion to UTC

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have tried my best to convert one textbox to UTC using the SSRS expression. It is not converting it. Is there any settings to configure before this code can work ? i used these two code below. Nothing works!

```
=TimezoneInfo.ConvertTimetoUtc(CDate(Fields!Starttime.Value))    

=DateTime.SpecifyKind(Fields!Starttime.Value, DateTimeKind.UTC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the expression below

```
=Fields!Starttime.Value.ToUniversalTime()
```

Design & Result with sample data

[image]

[image]

Comment: The ToUniversaltime is not recognised with the dot . It only has Equals and ReferenceEquals as option.

Comment: It's tested that it works with SSRS 2005 & 2016. Check the image from the report design and execution

Comment: It is given error in the textbox.  The time format is only in HH:mm

Comment: Is the database field type datetime?

Comment: Yes, it is datetime but it is an Access  DB connected through ODBC datasoource

Comment: Try =Cdate(Fields!Starttime.Value).ToUniversalTime()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174230/discussion-between-niktrs-and-great77).

Comment: Thanks, I wish I could have been more helpful